# How to assign every i-th vector on the i-th axis the samue value in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a certain pattern on how I want to assign values in a numpy array, e.g. I have a specific vector and I want to set all (i,i,:)-entries in some 3-dimensional array to that vector, what would be a numpythonic way to do this without a for-loop?

I.e. how to do this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange((5))

X = np.zeros((3,3,5))

for i in range(3):
    X[i,i,:]=x
```

```
Out: 
array([[[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange((5))

X = np.zeros((3,3,5))
X[range(3), range(3), :] = x

X
array([[[0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3., 4.]]])
```

For more general reference to slicing and indexing you can check numpy [array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
guide.